# What's wrong with this SQL (Subquery using IN)?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working with a junction table in Access (actually a self-join table which defines a parent>child relationship) and am running into trouble with some of the joins I need to make.

I currently have the following in one query:

```
(SELECT AccountID
FROM tblAccount
WHERE AccountTypeID IN (1, 2))
UNION (SELECT ChildAccountID 
FROM qryAccJunctionDetails
WHERE (ParentAccountTypeID IN (1, 2)));
```

Which works correctly: It provides a list of `AccountID`s where the `AccountTypeID` is 1 or 2, or where that account is the child of another account with `AccountTypeID` = 1 or 2.

When I then try to use this as a subquery to find other field values related to this result like so:

```
SELECT AccountName 
FROM qryAccountNamesConcat
WHERE AccountID IN(
    (
        SELECT AccountID
        FROM tblAccount
        WHERE AccountTypeID IN (1, 2)
    )
    UNION (
        SELECT ChildAccountID 
        FROM qryAccJunctionDetails
        WHERE (ParentAccountTypeID IN (1, 2))
    )
);
```

I get the error: `"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'AccountID IN(...."` which then continues to list right through to the end of the statement.

I've tried variations on it and can't seem to get it to work. It may be that I'm misunderstanding entirely how to put subqueries together in this way.

Edit: Now fixed missing parenthesis at the end of `(ParentAccountTypeID IN (1, 2))` but still getting the same error.

Comment: You're missing a paren at the end of the `WHERE (ParentAccountTypeID IN (1, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this with two separate comparisons:

```
SELECT AccountName 
FROM qryAccountNamesConcat
WHERE AccountID IN (SELECT AccountID
                    FROM tblAccount
                    WHERE AccountTypeID IN (1, 2)
                   ) OR
      AccountID IN (SELECT ChildAccountID 
                    FROM qryAccJunctionDetails
                    WHERE ParentAccountTypeID IN (1, 2)
                   );
```

This may also have better performance.

Comment: This does now work, but I'm curious as to why my original version didn't work correctly since as far as I can see it should work. Any ideas as to what I've done wrong?

Comment: Im also curious as to why the code i posted below would not work

Comment: @Alex . . . Your code has two sets of parentheses, which might throw Access off.  Plus, Access is quite finicky about `union` in subqueries.  They may not be allowed in this context.  Access is sufficiently different from the standard and from other databases that it is hard to say why it doesn't work, when it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

close the parenthesis, try this

```
SELECT AccountName 
FROM qryAccountNamesConcat
WHERE AccountID IN(
    (
        SELECT AccountID
        FROM tblAccount
        WHERE AccountTypeID IN (1, 2)
    )
    UNION (
        SELECT ChildAccountID 
        FROM qryAccJunctionDetails
        WHERE (ParentAccountTypeID IN (1, 2)) <-- here
    )
);
```

Comment: Ah yes I was, but I still get the same error after fixing it.

Comment: maybe we need ; after each subquerries

Comment: Nope, still get the same error after adding these in.

Comment: Bah, i guess you could try gordon's code. He's the master here. I'll try to help you if his code doesn't work

Comment: Gordon's code does work but I'd still like to understand what was wrong, to improve my general understanding of how I should be using SQL.